# How to Send Specific Frequency Through Audio Jack

Tags: audio, frequency

I'd like to send a specific frequency through an audio jack. I've looked into some audio synthesis programs, but I haven't found any that can output specific frequencies. 
Thanks for any advice!

Comment: Get an old VIC-20. You can specify frequency, wave form, amplitude, attack, sustain, decay, release, all very easily with a few commands in BASIC. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Commodore_VIC-20